# R check equality of one column to rowSums of other columns

Tags: r, equality, rowsum

I have a dataframe like this:

| x | y | x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to find rows that x=x1+x2+x3 and rows that y=y1+y2+y3.
Here is my code to check x=x1+x2+x3:

```
col_x = c(3,5,7)
df[df$x == rowSums(df[col_x])]
```

Suppose return row 1,3,4, but it returned

```
  x x1 y1 x2 x3 y3
1 1  1  0  0  0  0
2 0  3  0  0  0  0
3 2  0  0  0  2  0
4 1  0  0  1  0  0
```

I also tried

```
col_x = c(3,5,7)
df[df$x == apply(df[col_x],1,sum)]
```

Which also give me:

```
  x x1 y1 x2 x3 y3
1 1  1  0  0  0  0
2 0  3  0  0  0  0
3 2  0  0  0  2  0
4 1  0  0  1  0  0
```

I can't figure out why it returned all rows and it had skip column y2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a comma.

```
col_x = c(3,5,7)
df[df$x == rowSums(df[col_x]),]

  x y x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
1 1 0  1  0  0  0  0  0
3 2 0  0  0  0  0  2  0
4 1 0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: I can't beleive that's the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(x == rowSums(across(matches("x\\d$"))) &
    y == rowSums(across(matches("y\\d$"))))

#>   x y x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
#> 1 1 0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#> 2 2 0  0  0  0  0  2  0
#> 3 1 0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: That's a nice work around too!